# Checking which Page is set to Frames content in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

I have a wpf application with a frame (ContentFrame). I want to know how to find out which page is loaded in that frame and do something if it is the ViewDataPage.

```
if(ContentFrame.Content == ViewDataPage)
{
    // Do Something.
}
```

I have tried referencing the ViewDataPage in several ways with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the type of content.

EG
I have a page

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.WizardMainPage"
```

With markup:

```
<Grid>
    <Frame Source="WizardMainPage.xaml" Name="MyFrame">
    </Frame>
    <Button Content="Check" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Click="Button_Click_1"/>
</Grid>
```

Click the button and check matching type:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyFrame.Content is WizardMainPage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("True");
            //Code gets to here
        }
    }
```